# How to link Room database entities on android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-room

I am quite familiar with these kind of thing on Spring JPA but I can not make it work on Android. I post my code below so you can understand the question better. I have two classes and a third class that needs to contain objects of class 1 and 2. I know that the code for the third class is not correct, since Room does not support object references like that. If I save just the id-s of the objects as foreign keys I am not able to query after the results.

There must be some kind of nice solution for this problem. Thank you.

```
@Entity(tableName = "soup")
public class Soup {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private long id;
    private String name;

    // getter and setters
}

@Entity(tableName = "main_course")
public class MainCourse {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private long id;
    private String name;

    // getter and setters
}

@Entity(tableName = "menu")
public class Menu {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private long id;

    private Soup soupOptionOne;
    private Soup soupOptionTwo;
    private Soup soupOptionThree;

    private MainCourse courseOptionOne;
    private MainCourse courseOptionTwo;
    private MainCourse courseOptionThree;
}
```

Comment: Use @Embeded,refer https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data#nested-objects

Comment: I saw the @Embedded annotation, but that creates additional fields in the table where it is used. I would like to have 3 separate tables in this case.